# Why does the void_t<> detection idiom not work with gcc-4.9?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++14, sfinae

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Test { Test& operator++(); };
struct NoIncrement { };

template <typename...> using void_t = void;

template <class, class=void_t<>>
struct has_pre_increment_member : std::false_type { };

template <class T>
struct has_pre_increment_member<T, void_t<decltype( ++std::declval<T&>() )>>
  : public std::true_type { };

int main() {
  std::cout << has_pre_increment_member<Test>::value << " ";
  std::cout << has_pre_increment_member<NoIncrement>::value << std::endl;
}
```

With g++ version 5 and later (and the -std=c++14 flag, of course), this code outputs

```
1 0
```

as it should.  With g++ version 4.9 (and the -std=c++14 flag), however, it outputs

```
1 1
```

Both claim to be using the same language standard, so what's the issue here?

Comment: Are you using 4.9.0 or is it higher than that?  I have seen some bugs in 4.9.0 that were fixed if you go to 4.9.2.

Comment: Well that was all I could contribute.  if it makes you fell any better it works on clang too.

Comment: This has at least been filed as a [bug in version 4.9.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2014-12/msg02669.html).

Comment: Oh, wonderful @callyalater.  It's good to know I'm not using the language incorrectly.  Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This comes about as a result of [CWG Issue 1558](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558), and is now considered a bug in gcc (specifically [64395](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64395) - currently fixed). The idea behind the issue is that since you don't actually use the template parameters here:

```
template <typename...> using void_t = void;
```

there's no substitution failure regardless of what types or expressions you try to pass in.

Thankfully, there's an easy workaround that doesn't involve upgrading your compiler. We can rewrite `void_t` to actually use its parameter pack, thereby triggering the substitution failure:

```
namespace void_details {
    template <class... >
    struct make_void { using type = void; };
}

template <class... T> using void_t = typename void_details ::make_void<T...>::type;
```

That'll make your example do the right thing across all the gcc versions I tried.